# tweetsharp - retweet user's tweet from my app's account

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I have an asp.net Web Forms C# application, that uses Tweetsharp to allow my users to connect their Twitter account. When the user performs a certain action on my site, they have an opportunity to tweet a link to that action.

All this is working fine, but I'd like to extend the functionality and am unsure where to begin as various google searches have turned up blanks.

Essentially what I'd like to do is, once the user has sent their tweet, is call my App's twitter account to retweet that tweet.

My best guess is that the steps I'd need to do are:

1. get the tweet ID of the tweet the user has sent
2. connect to my app's Twitter account
3. retweet the user's tweet

I'd be ok with steps 2 and 3, but I'm not sure about step 1. Is there some way for me to get the tweet id of the user's tweet?

---

Edit - this is how i authenticate the user and send their Tweet:

```
TwitterClientInfo twitterClientInfo = new TwitterClientInfo();
    twitterClientInfo.ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey;
    twitterClientInfo.ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret;
    TwitterService twitterService = new TwitterService(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
    twitterService.AuthenticateWith(accessTokenFromDB, accessokenSecretFromDB);
    TwitterUser user = twitterService.VerifyCredentials(new VerifyCredentialsOptions());

    SendTweetOptions options = new SendTweetOptions();
    options.Status = tweetText;
    twitterService.SendTweet(options);
```

Comment: How are you submitting the tweet? Is there some return data that has the tweet ID? Have you looked at the API to see what the JSON(assuming it's JSON) is returning? If the API returns the info, but the library doesn't, you may need to edit the library.

Comment: Hi @ernest - I've just edited the question with my "send tweet" code. There doesn't seem to be anything in that that returns any data. I'm not particularly experienced with Tweetsharp which was really the crux of my question - is there a way to send a tweet with Tweetsharp that can return the tweet id?